# How to customize Display Template Hover Panel Header

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, display-template

I'm trying to customize the Header portion of my hover panel.  The header is called in the Default Hover Panel like so:

```
<div id="_#= $htmlEncode(id + HP.ids.header) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-header">
                    _#= ctx.RenderHeader(ctx) =#_ <BR>
<div style='color:#000000; display:inline'>This is a test </div>
```

My question is where do I change ctx.RenderHeader(ctx) to point to my custom header file?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "You don't". What you should do is create your own function to render your custom header (or use a static header) in your Display Template. The reason I say this is because if you change the built-in function you will be impacting every other display template and that can have unintended consequences. Also, any changes or updates pushed by Microsoft will not be picked up by your code.